# postfix queue file write error only when sending emails from smartphone

Tags: email, postfix

This might sound weird, but the thing is, that I cannot send emails from my smartphone even though it works from my desktop email client. I double-checked that the smtp settings are correct.

This is the status log I am getting as error messages:

```
Transcript of session follows.

 Out: 220 ****.tld ESMTP Postfix (Debian/GNU)
 In:  EHLO [IP ADDRESS]
 Out: 250-****.tld
 Out: 250-PIPELINING
 Out: 250-SIZE 26214400
 Out: 250-VRFY
 Out: 250-ETRN
 Out: 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN
 Out: 250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
 Out: 250-8BITMIME
 Out: 250 DSN
 In:  AUTH PLAIN SOME_LONG_CODE
 Out: 235 2.7.0 Authentication successful
 In:  MAIL FROM:<xxx@***.tld>
 Out: 250 2.1.0 Ok
 In:  RCPT TO:<a@b.tld>
 Out: 451 4.3.0 Error: queue file write error
 In:  QUIT
 Out: 221 2.0.0 Bye
```

What is this? Authentication seems to work fine, and I am not sending attachments. (That is mainly what I get when I google that error, that attachments are too big). As I said: It works from thunderbird but doesn't from my smartphone. (Android with K-9 Mail).

What could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you tried sending emails with another email client from your smartphone? Trying to see if this is a bug in the way K-9 is handling the message or not.

Comment: I am pretty sure it is not. I have never had problems with K-9 and this just doesn't feel like it's a bug of the software. If I cannot solve it soon, I will of course need to dig into that as well, but it used to work before (though I can't remember anymore what I changed...).

Comment: From what I gather, that message usually only shows up when something to do with space/size is an issue. Is your data plan all used up (assuming you're on 3G)?